# error MSB3216 when registering assembly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, com, windows-7

Here are the error details:

In the Error List:

> Error 1   Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\cboardman\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1\bin\Debug\ExcelAddIn1.dll" - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ExcelAddIn1...' is denied.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets    3019    9   ExcelAddIn1

In the Build Output:

> Target UnmanagedRegistration:
>       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(3019,9): error MSB3216: Cannot register assembly "C:\Users\cboardman\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ExcelAddIn1\ExcelAddIn1\bin\Debug\ExcelAddIn1.dll" - access denied. Please make sure you're running the application as administrator. Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ExcelAddIn1...' is denied.
>   Done building target "UnmanagedRegistration" in project "ExcelAddIn1.csproj" -- FAILED.

From what I have found online, I need to be running Visual Studio as administrator.  This seems like a big hammer for a small nail.  Is there a way around this (like a way to run just the registration as administrator)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not an easy way to do this.  By default registering the components adds entries to protected keys in the registry (under HKLM in particular).  This cannot be done without administrative rights.

It is technically possible to register COM components as a non-admin by using the equivalent keys under HKCU.  However it is not a trivial change and I do not believe the .Net tools which register the assemblies can be configured to do this.

I think your best option is to disable registration during build.  Then have a separate Admin window open where you can hand register the DLL From for debugging purposes.  The re-registration is only really necessary if you change the COM related interfaces or location of the DLL so it doesn't have to be done for every F5.

Answer (score 6):

Closing Visual Studio and re-opening right-clicking on it -> Run as Administrator solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem with Visual Studio 2017.

[JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3119436) led me to this implementation:

- Goto the project's properties
- Select Build
- Untick `Register for COM interop` [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzldD.png)
- Select Build Events
- add a Post-build event command line:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir %windir%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\regasm.exe /s /b') do set current_regasm="%%a"
set command=%current_regasm% $(TargetPath) /tlb:$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).tlb /codebase ^; sleep 2
set elevated_command="Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Wait -ArgumentList \"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %command%\"
powershell -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %elevated_command% -Verb RunAs"
```

- In the drop-down `run the post-build event:` select: `On successful build` [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G81MO.png)
- Run a build

At the end of the build you will see a powershell window run as administrator (depending on your settings you may have a User Account Control (UAC) popup asking you to confirm before it will run).

Note:

- This will find the latest .NET framework version and use regasm from there (credit: [Scott C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42500423)).
- Increase the `; sleep 2` if you want longer to look at the output to confirm the registration (or use `; pause` instead).