# How can I correct this ADODB missing reference error in VB .NET that I'm getting after upgrading to Windows 10?

Tags: vb.net, reference, windows-10, adodb, recordset

After upgrading to Windows 10, I got a lot of errors relating to a broken ADODB reference in my VB .NET application. I performed the steps described in the answer from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718550/vs-2012-3-referencing-ms-access-com-dll-could-not-resolve-com-reference-error) and that seemed to fix the broken reference errors. That solution actually got the application working for some of my colleagues on their Windows 10 systems. Unfortunately, anywhere in the application where I'm using a Recordset, I'm still getting this error:

"Reference required to assembly 'ADODB, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type 'ADODB.Recordset'. Add one to your project."

When I investigated some more, I found that the reference's location was "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado25.tlb". With this path, I tried to register msado25.tlb type library using Tlbimp.exe but it didn't seem to help any.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something stupid but I have no idea what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here are some additional related screenshots that may help:

[ADODB Reference Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhhky.png)

[Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yUhP.png)

Comment: You did too much damage to the registry on that machine to still make sense of the screen shots.  This is the kind of mishap you get when you start a project to target .NET 4.0 or up and then downgrade to 3.5 or less.  The version number is wrong, the screenshot shows 2.5.0.0 but it must be 7.0.3300.0.  Maybe you can rescue it by selecting the PIA by hand.  Remove the ADODB reference from the project.  Project > Add Reference > Browse button and navigate to c:\windows\assembly\adodb.

Comment: The registry on my coworker's workstations match the one on mine. I don't think there's any damage done there. The solution I'm using has always been targeting .Net 3.5, it has never targeted .Net 4.0. I have tried adding 7.0.3300.0 (no need to browse, it's available through Assemblies -> Extensions)  but I get a whole host of other errors when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue after the Windows 10 Anniversary update  and I solved it by using tlbimp.exe. tlbimp generates a new adodb.dll and you can reference this in your project.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\tlbimp.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado21.tlb"

The Type Library Importer converts the type definitions found within a COM type library into equivalent definitions in a common language runtime assembly.

Comment: I could have swore I previously did that. I'm really glad I tried again though because it worked this time. Thanks so much for your time and effort.