# Why has my ADODB.dll reference changed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, adodb

I have a legacy VB.NET application that was originally written in MSVS2010 (or possibly earlier). It contains a COM reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library, i.e. ADODB.dll, located at `FooProject\obj\x86\Debug\Interop.ADODB.dll`.

I have been developing on this application on my Windows 10 PC using MSVS2017, but recently when I try to run on the Windows 7 machines for which its use is intended I get errors about the ADODB reference, that the wrapper assembly is missing.

I have checked that the targeted platform is set to x86 (the Win 7 machines are 32-bit, my dev machine is 64-bit). But the error persisted. Looking back through commits I can find where the problem was introduced. During some changes to a MSSQL DB table (adding columns) and subsequent update of the LINQ-to-SQL DBML file, the wrapper setting on the ADODB reference in the vbproj file appears to have changed from tlbimp to primary.

While it doesn't show in the commit history, the path of the reference also changes, to `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\ADODB\7.0.33.00.0_b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ADODB.dll`

Now I guess I could just change the path back maybe, but as this is related to auto-generated code (the DBML and the VBPROJ) I'm not sure if the dll in the `obj` should be counted on to always be there, and if this is the correct way to go about it referencing it? I thought that to decide on the right course of action it would help to understand *why* this change occurred... can anyone tell me?

This *may* be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813023/how-can-i-correct-this-adodb-missing-reference-error-in-vb-net-that-im-getting), but I am just not sure.

**UPDATE:**
After some fiddling about on the Windows 7 machines I changed the reference to a different version (2.8 -> 6.0) and then back again... Now the reference path is back to the `obj` one and the project builds. However, this does *not* work on my Windows 10 machine, which I would need to have match so that I'm not constantly trying to switch back and forth between the different references.

I notice that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718550/vs-2012-3-referencing-ms-access-com-dll-could-not-resolve-com-reference-error) talks about a similar issue, but none of the solutions there worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried setting the COM reference to be embedded?  In the Solution Explorer (show all files)->References->ADODB->right click properties, set "Embed Interop Types" to true.

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks, Embed Interop Types is already set to True for this reference in my project

Comment: For future reference, I simply removed the reference from the project as as far as I could tell it wasn't being used. I did have to setup my database connection again, though I am unsure if this was directly related or not, and it has built and worked just fine since.