# Using C# dll in C++ codes without using Regasm

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, com

I have created a C++ application which uses a C# dll following the link as shown below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

The application works fine on my development PC , but when I tried to run it on another PC , it fails.

The only way to make it work is to recompile the C# dll on that PC and run the Regasm command again on that PC to work .

Is there a way to build my C# dll in such a way so that I do not have to do this every single time on every PC my application is deployed to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What regasm does is generate a COM wrapper for your C# dll and then registers it as a COM object.

You do not need to recompile though, once you have a dll you can register it on the target [PC using regasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973939/how-to-run-regasm-exe-from-command-line-other-than-visual-studio-command-prompt).

The main other way to call a C# dll is to write a C++ .net program using the C++/CLI system from Microsoft. This is basically a way of [creating .NET programs using a superset of C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes) (hint: its not C++, which is a shame as the old managed extensions it replaces was much more transparent for this task). As its not 'true' C++ you'll end up with a .NET binary instead of a C++ one, so be aware of this. One aspect is that you could write a C++/CLI wrapper to the C# dll and call that from your C++ program, this is probably the preferred way of creating a bridge between the systems.

Comment: If i were to write a wrapper to the C# dll , wouldn't I still need to perform RegAsm on the client PC ? For Example C++ program will call my C++/CLI wrapperClass which in turn still calls the C# dll ?

Comment: No. You only need Regasm because you're turning the c# DLL into a com object. If you write a c++/CLI wrapper it will be a normal c++ DLL but you'll have to deal with the interop with the c# one "manually". Have a Google and find a tutorial fit details.

Answer (score 0):

I did this, and it worked, copy and paste the code on cmd

```
 %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe MyAssembly.dll
```

Kindly vote if it works for you. :D